# Import content to Tridion 2011 from Tridion 5.3

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is it possible to export content from Tridion 5.3 and import it in Tridion 2011 sp1? if yes how to do it? We have SDL Content Porter 2009 SP1 installed on Tridion 2011 SP1 server.

Comment: you can find more details in the previous [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807778/what-is-best-way-to-migrate-content-from-tridion-5-3sp1-to-2011sp1

Comment: if you want to export all content , you can upgrade your 5.3 database to 2011 SP1 and point CME to this database.

Comment: We don't want to export entire content, we have some selected folders which we want to import in Tridion 2011 sp1

Answer (score 2):

So the situation is:

- you have a Tridion 2011 installation with a database which has some content you want to keep
- you have a Tridion 5.3 installation which contains some content you want port to the 2011 instance

One possible approach is this:

- Upgrade the 5.3 database to 2011 using the standard upgrade tools and link it to your Tridion 2011 instance
- Link your 2011 instance to this database (instead of your current 2011 db)
- Export the items you need with the Content Porter
- Switch back to the original 2011 db
- Import the items again with the Content Porter